# Saving a value to a global variable

Tags: typescript, angular

How can I a save value to a global variable in a component and use it in different component? I tried to implement static varible but it doesn't seem to work as I thought it would (I'm getting undefined for value in different component).

Edit: forgot to add that I don't want to use a service for reasons.

Static code I've tried and couldn't get to work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RwVar8XneKfpm6RJSPyi?p=preview

```
export class MyClass {
  static _someVal: string;

  get someVal() => MyClass._someVal;
  set someVal(value: string) => MyClass._someVal = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variable works, but you can also use a shared service.
See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

For a static variable you need to add a getter because static variables can't be accessed from the template.

```
export class MyComponent {
  static _someVal = 123;

  get someVal() => MyComponent.someVal;
}
```

then you can get `123` in the template like

```
{{someVal}}
```

If you change your main.ts to

```
MyClass.MyVar = "test";

bootstrap(App, [])
.then((appRef: ComponentRef) => {

});
```

then the value is shown in `AppComponent`

Comment: Terribly sorry I forgot to add that I don't want to use a service (don't ask)

Comment: Added plunker with your sample. I set in main.ts and try to use it in app.ts but it's undefined. What am I missing? (I need to set it in the promise)

Comment: I don't know yet why it doesn't update if you set it in `then(...)` but if you set it before its working. See my updated answer.

Comment: It's just because you copy the value in the constructor of `AppComponent` which is executed before `bootstrap(...).then(...). http://plnkr.co/edit/TI7YGNqyGv0pDwtdmAR8?p=preview

Comment: I see. Static variables would be unsuitable in my case. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Why would it be unsuitable?

Comment: Because I need the value in the constructor.

Comment: Then just set the static value before `bootstrap()` like shown in my answer above.

Comment: Yes I just realized it was the event order problem not static variables fault. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a shared service and set my values in it. This service is a simple class that needs to be specified when bootstrapping the application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

You can then inject it into component and put data in it that will be shared by all components (and services as well). Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private service:SharedService) {
    this.service.globalData = { ... };
  }
}
```

**Edit**

You could export a data container from a module (for example `yourmodule`):

```
export var dataContainer = {
  globalData: {}
};
```

and import it from other module:

```
import {dataContainer} from 'yourmodule';

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor() {
   dataContainer.globalData = { ... };
  }
}
```